# Feasibility of a bit modified version of Rabin Karp algorithm

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, hash

I am trying to implement a bit modified version of Rabin Karp algorithm. My idea is if I get a hash value of the given pattern in terms of weight associated with each letter, then I don't have to worry about anagrams so I can just pick up a part of the string, calculate its hash value and compare with hash value of the pattern unlike traditional approach where hashvalue of both part of string and pattern is calculated and then checked whether they are actually similar or it could be an anagram. Here is my code below

```
string = "AABAACAADAABAABA"
pattern = "AABA"
#string = "gjdoopssdlksddsoopdfkjdfoops"
#pattern = "oops"

#get hash value of the pattern
def gethashp(pattern):
    sum = 0
    #I mutiply each letter of the pattern with a weight
    #So for eg CAT will be C*1 + A*2 + T*3 and the resulting
    #value wil be unique for the letter CAT and won't match if the
    #letters are rearranged
    for i in range(len(pattern)):
        sum = sum + ord(pattern[i]) * (i + 1)
    return sum % 101 #some prime number 101

def gethashst(string):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        sum = sum + ord(string[i]) * (i + 1)
    return sum % 101

hashp = gethashp(pattern)
i = 0
def checkMatch(string,pattern,hashp):
    global i 
    #check if we actually get first four strings(comes handy when you 
    #are nearing the end of the string)
    if len(string[:len(pattern)]) == len(pattern):
        #assign the substring to string2
        string2 = string[:len(pattern)]
        #get the hash value of the substring
        hashst = gethashst(string2)
        #if both the hashvalue matches
        if hashst == hashp:
            #print the index of the first character of the match
            print("Pattern found at {}".format(i))
        #delete the first character of the string
        string = string[1:]
        #increment the index
        i += 1 #keep a count of the index
        checkMatch(string,pattern,hashp)
    else:
        #if no match or end of string,return
        return

checkMatch(string,pattern,hashp)
```

The code is working just fine. My question is this a valid way of doing it? Can there be any instance where the logic might fail? All the Rabin Karp algorithms that I have come across doesn't use this logic instead for every match, it furthers checks character by character to ensure it's not an anagram. So is it wrong if I do it this way? My opinion is with this code as soon as the hash value matches, you never have to further check both the strings character by character and you can just move on to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary that only anagrams collide with the hash value of the pattern. Any other string with same hash value could also collide. Same hash value can act as a liar, so character by character match is required.

For example in your case, you are taking mod 100. Take any distinct 101 patterns, then by the Pigeonhole principle, at least two of them would be having the same hash. If you use one of them as a pattern then the presence of other string would err your output if you avoid character match.

Moreover, even with the hash you used, two anagrams can have the same hash value which can be obtained by solving two linear equations.
For example,

```
DCE = 4*1 + 3*2 + 5*3 = 25
CED = 3*1 + 5*2 + 4*3 = 25
```

Comment: Wow!That's a brilliant insight!Thanks for sharing your knowledge and pointing out the flaw in the code :)